# htaccess: access url only with the foldername

Tags: php, apache

I have the following structure:

/ONEFOLDER/OTHERFOLDER/myarchive/myarchive.php

I would like to access:

/ONEFOLDER/OTHERFOLDER/myarchive/

"myarchive" could be anything but it is always repeated in the file

how can I write it in an htaccess file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define a default index file to be served by your server in the .htaccess file by adding the following directive:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html myarchive.php
```

In case .htaccess is not present, simply create it.

**update**

In case I did not understand the question correctly, and you simply want to map the folder name to the file name, then Apache's Mod Rewrite is your ultimate voodoo doll for these operations. You will have to add an .htaccess file in the /ONEFOLDER/OTHERFOLDER/ directory and add the following content:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([-a-zA-Z0-9_//]+)/?$ $1/$1.php?%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

Which will basically route any Folder name to the matching folder name/file name DOT php